# Receive String from two post method- Java Rest

Tags: java, rest, post, client

I've been writing for a long time a Java Rest application and I want to send user name and file context using Post method.

I have two methods in Client's code:

```
public void postUser(String user)

public void postFile(File myFile)
```

These two methods send string.

And my Server's post method, which receive string from postUser method:

```
@Post                                       
public void userPost(String name) {
User.getInstance().addUser(name);
}
```

I want to receive string from postFile method and save it to diffrent varaible than in userPost method. What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do I understand it correctly? You want to invoke something like...

```
postUser(user);
postFile(myFile);
```

and in the client, to process the two different requests in some stateful manner(the receiver is supposed to know that ).

```
@Post                                       
public void userPost(String name) {
User.getInstance().addUser(name);
}

@Post                                       
public void filePost(File file) {
//processing the file, ONLY IF the userPost method is already invoked
}
```

Instead, can you encapsulate the two requests in one(one request with two parameters). Something like

```
 postUserFile(user,file);
```

And in the request reciever...

```
@Post                                       
public void nameFilePost(String name, File file) {
  userPost(name);
  filePost(file)
}
```

I don't recognize the framework which you are using, but in [JAX-RS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_RESTful_Web_Services) the method will looks something like this

```
@PATH("/yourPath/")
public class YourClassNameHere{

@POST                                    
public void nameFilePost(@QueryParam("name") String name, @QueryParam("file") File file) {
  userPost(name);
  filePost(file)
  }
}
```

One last thing: Don't use Singletons, they are global variables, and therefore bad. [Why global variables are bad.](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad)

Comment: Thank you for Your response. However, I would like to have this two method independent, because I won't send this two data in the same time( files more often than user name). I'm using Restlet as my framework

Comment: Ok, I understand. Check this article http://blog.ianbicking.org/rest-in-more-than-one-request.html and you can read more about statefull REST services in general.